How to fetch data via SwiftData?
I'm new to SwiftData. I seem to have managed to save a model into datastore, however I don't know how to get it back.
The line with context.fetch() fails with the error message:
Cannot convert value of type 'CharacterModel.Type' to expected argument type 'FetchDescriptor<T>'

class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()
    
    func saveCharacter(_ character: Character, context: ModelContext) {
        let characterModel = CharacterModel(
            name: character.name,
            subtitle: character.subtitle,
            description: character.description,
            tags: character.tags,
            imageName: character.imageName,
            creator: character.creator,
            AI: character.AI,
            chatHistory: character.chatHistory,
            userBackgroundStory: character.userBackgroundStory
        )
        
        do {
            try context.insert(characterModel)
            try context.save()
            print("Character saved successfully.")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving character: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func loadCharacter(withID id: UUID, context: ModelContext) -> Character? {
        guard let characterModel = try? context.fetch(CharacterModel.self, where: \.id == id).first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let character = Character(
            name: characterModel.name,
            subtitle: characterModel.subtitle,
            description: characterModel.characterDescription,
            tags: characterModel.tags,
            imageName: characterModel.imageName,
            creator: characterModel.creator,
            AI: characterModel.AI,
            chatHistory: characterModel.chatHistory,
            userBackgroundStory: characterModel.userBackgroundStory ?? ""
        )
        
        return character
    }
}

What am I missing, please?
UPDATE:
I don't think the naming is an issue. The model itself is called CharacterModel and Character is a struct, unrelated to the model itself.
@Model
class CharacterModel: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let subtitle: String
    let characterDescription: String
    let tags: [String]
    let imageName: String
    let creator: String
    let AI: String
    var chatHistory: [String]
    var userBackgroundStory: String

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, subtitle: String, description: String, tags: [String], imageName: String, creator: String, AI: String, chatHistory: [String] = [], userBackgroundStory: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.characterDescription = description
        self.tags = tags
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.creator = creator
        self.AI = AI
        self.chatHistory = chatHistory
        self.userBackgroundStory = userBackgroundStory
    }
}


You need to pass a FetchDescriptor to the fetch method. Some reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/fetchdescriptor, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata

Maybe unrelated but Character is a type in Standard Library. Rename your type to avoid unexpected behavior.

Thanks will check it out.  Why the down vote / close? I provided code, with example and error message. SO's exceptionalism is sometimes insane.

No the naming is not the problem here, just read the documentation I linked to in the first comment.

I assume you have resolved this by now, time to close this question?

Why do you want to close the question? Question should be answered so others have a point of reference in future. "Read the documentation" is not an answer. What do you gain by closing the question, if it has a clear structure with code examples included? You are here for 6 years, you should know better how this works.

Why not post an answer yourself then?
